# List comprehension to normalize values in a matrix

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a matrix of values, like:

```
matrix = [
[1,2,3],
[5,6,7]
]
```

I want to normalize them, so that each row sums to one. This is pretty simple with an approach like:

```
result = []
for x in matrix:
    curr_row = [z/sum(x) for z in x]
    result.append(curr_row)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with a list comprehension.

The closest I've gotten is

`result = [x/sum(y) for y in matrix for x in y]`

but this collapses it all into one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
from __future__ import division        # for Python2

results = [[item/sum(row) for item in row] for row in matrix] # a list of lists

print(results)
# Output
[[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5], [0.2777777777777778, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3888888888888889]]
```

Comment: IMO it's important to notice here that you wanted the result to be a matrix (or list-of-lists), and thus you needed a nested list comprehension.

Comment: @turbulencetoo, what does `IMO` stand for?